# Open an .mdf (Master Databse File) on mac or attach it to MySQL

Tags: mysql, windows, macos, mdf

I have a .mdf file which I've downloaded on my mac and I have no idea what to do with it. I get the impression it was designed for a windows environment and not for a mac or for MySQL. I need a way to either open it so I can see what's inside and create my own database similar in complexity

OR even better

find a way to attach it to MySQL so I can run queries against it.

Any advice on what I should do?